# Redux-Form (V6) & Materialize.css 's Radio Button not working

Tags: materialize, redux-form, input-field, react-redux-form

I am having trouble combining with Redux-Form and Materialize.css's radio button.

Because of the syntax issue ( I believe `label` is the cause of it), if I combine both, it stops working (meaning that I cannot select any of the radio buttons). 
If I take out the materialize.css, Redux-Form works properly.

Is it possible to combine both of these?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
  render() {
    const { chartData, chartOptions } = this.state;
    const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <main className="welcome container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col center-align s12">
            <h3>Title of the Poll</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <BarChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions}/>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12">
              <p>
                <Field name="category" component="input" type="radio" value="male"/>
                <label>Male</label>
              </p>
              <p>
                <Field name="category" component="input" type="radio" value="female"/>
                <label>Female</label>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="col input-field s12">
              <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                <i className="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </main>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at CSS, it looked like by Materialze.css default, the html's input radio button has a `left` property of `99px` which goes away from the screen.

Knowing that, I had to just insert a custom CSS on my own to move the input and align it above the radio button that materilize renders.

Here's what I came up with:

**css**

```
.radio-button-css{
  position: relative !important;
  z-index: 12;
  // opacity: 1 !important;
  left: 18px !important;
}
```

Notice I've inserted `radio-button-css` inside the Field attribute

```
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col s12">
          <p>
            <Field name="category" component="input" type="radio" className="radio-button-css" value="male"/>
            <label>Male</label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <Field name="category" component="input" type="radio" className="radio-button-css" value="female"/>
            <label>Female</label>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="col input-field s12">
          <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i className="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

From there, adjust the `left` property in the `radio-button-css` and after you are finish, set the opacity back to zero ( you need to set one to actual see the html's radio button)